# C# .net 3.5 inter process communication verify the child process has started ok

Tags: c#, process

I have parent process that use process.start(..) for a another process.
The child process will later on have WCF service that i call an Initialized() on it.
Before calling any methods, I would like to verify and make sure the process has started ok.
right now my code is:

```
Process driverProcess = new Process();
driverProcess.StartInfo.FileName = ".."
driverProcess.Start();
```

and then i use my WCF Service client:

```
client.Initialize(..);
```

It is working since process is starting ok, but i dont have any indication for this.

E.g if the computer does not allow to start new process, the Process.Start() wont work, and my client will try to .initialize() an non-existing WCF service.

What technique can i use in order to know the process has started ? Named pipes client-server?

**I CANT use process.WaitForInputIdle()** since this is Winform application that i removed the form1() from it. "Gui less window application".

Comment: Not being able to connect to the WCF service is a pretty good hint.  It is the best one since it will also work if the process started okay but then fell over trying to initialize the service.  Other than that you can typically rely on a non-zero Process.ExitCode after it exited.

Comment: Hi Hans thanks for reminding me about this question, i posted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I used in the end was EventWaitHandle.
I named the event on Parent process with its process Id, when I created the child process, I sent as arg the parent process Id.
When child process finishes its initialization, It creates a new ManualResetEvent with same name (parent process id from arg[0]) and .Set() it.

**Parent Process code:**

```
Process newProcess= new Process();  
newProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "YourProcessPath+FileName.exe" //use CombinePath  
newProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);  
var handle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString());
handle.Reset();
handle.WaitOne(); //wait until event is Set() from child Process
```

**Code in child process:**

```
signalParentProcessImReady = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, args[0]);  
DoWwork()... initialize WCF Services for example...
signalParentProcessImReady .Set(); //Signal parent process Im ready
```

Comment: After investigation, the above works because: "The EventWaitHandle class provides access to named system synchronization events", so all events of this type, created with same name in the same computer, can be set/reset no matter from what process the object was created.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the boolean value of the Start() method. Besides you can associate an Exited event handler to the process to tell your app that the app has finished. This way you can also know if it started and ended right after.

*EDIT:* i forgot to mention that you can also put your starting code inside a try block and check for exceptions that might be thrown by Start() method.